# How Can I Determine Whether The UIImagePickerController Has Finished Switching CameraModes?

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating an application that allows gestures to change the camera mode (photo or video) and camera device (front or rear). However, currently, I am encountering issues due to the time these switches take. For example, if a setting is being changed, another gesture will simply be ignored by the device. I would like to somehow determine that the change is still occurring and be alerted once it has finished the switch, so that I can indicate to the user that the requests are busy.

An example of what I want is the built in camera where the picture button is disabled and the screen is blurred while the change is occurring, and then they are re-enabled once it is done. Is that just a set delay, or is there a better way to determine that the job is done?